# How to modify a model after bulk update in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I try some code like this:

```
mymodels = MyModel.objects.filter(status=1)
mymodels.update(status=4)
print(mymodels)
```

And the result is an empty list

I know that I can use a for loop to replace the update.

But it will makes a lot of update query.

Is there anyway to continue manipulate mymodels after the bulk update?

Comment: Django's QuerySets are lazy while the [`update` is applied immediately](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) so I'm going to guess that because you are changing the `status` with the update call, the `filter` is being applied lazily, i.e. after the `update`, meaning that the records `status` have changed in the meantime

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony this should be an answer :)

Comment: I've added it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mymodels = MyModel.objects.filter(status=1)
objs = [obj for obj in mymodels] # save the objects you are about to update
mymodels.update(status=4)
print(objs)
```

should work.

Explanations why had been given by Timmy O'Mahony.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use something like that. I'll change this line objs = [obj for obj in mymodels] to objs = list(mymodels)... seems a bit easy and better...

Answer (score 3):

Remember that [Django's QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy):

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated

but [the `update()` method function is actually applied immediately](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update):

> The update() method is applied instantly, and the only restriction on the QuerySet that is updated is that it can only update columns in the model’s main table, not on related models.

So while - in your code - are applying the `update` call after your `filter`, in reality it is being applied beforehand and therefore your objects `status` is being changed before the `filter` is (lazily) applied, meaning there are no matching records and the result is empty.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But it's not really solve my problem.. I want to manipulate the things I select after I update them. The ideal query in my mind is SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE... and then UPDATE TABLE COLUMN="value" WHERE ID IN (the previous query) and at the end I can use these ids to access all of the data. I am wondering is there any elegant and smart way to do that?